# Saving appSettings to an external file

Tags: c#, winforms, app-config, appsettings

I need to have appSettings in a separate file and in a parent directory and save it at runtime:

Bin/app.config:

```
<appSettings file="../Configuration/appSettings.config">
  <add key="commonSetting" value="123"/>
</appSettings>
```

Configuration/appSettings.config:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="externalSetting" value="ABC"/>
</appSettings>
```

When I try to modify and save external settings, they are saved in Bin\app.config instead of Configuration/appSettings.config:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["externalSetting"] = "DEF";
config.Save();
```

I can't use `configSource` attribute because external file has to be in a subdirectory of Bin.

(Similar problem raised in [AppSettings on a different .config file not being updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799413/appsettings-on-a-different-config-file-not-being-updated) but not the same constaints)

Any idea of how to fix / work around it?

**EDIT**:

I also tried with this setter, same unexpected result:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.AppSettings.Settings["externalSetting"].Value = "DEF";
config.Save();
```

Comment: Store the appsettings file in DB.

Comment: As an option, you can use the custom xml or json file to store a configuration

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Is it a work around, could you write an answer to explain?

Comment: @sinsedrix I have an example, how to store an settings in `json` file in any location, and custom wrapper around it. It uses `Newtonsoft` library, and not related to `System.Configuration`. I can post details, if it'll be helpful